# backing up microsoft outlook data for all client computers on network

Tags: outlook, google, email

I have 50 Microsoft Outlook users on my company network connected to Google Apps Mail. My requirement is to create a backup mechanism for backing up the Outlook data for all the users on a periodic basis. This is required as a backup support in case of corruption of data at user end.

I outlook we want to disable the option leave a copy of the message on sever so that the mailbox capacity of 15GB is not exhausted.

Please suggest the best possible way of achieving this.

Comment: It will provably be cheaper, and certainly more reliable, to pay google for more storage than to roll your own backups of PST files.  How do you plan to handle off site backups (in case your building catches fire)?  Leaving mail on the server gives you that with no extra effort or parts to fail.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are talking file backup here. Either periodically upload the .pst files to a central repository and backup from there (windows task), or use local backup clients to backup directly from the clients (backup software).

What backup software and medium you choose is up to you really, but it should be one with which you can restore on per-file basis (so no amazon glacier for instance).

Comment: make sure to do a cost-comparison between backing up 50X >15GB, and paying for larger mailboxes in google apps.

Comment: just a hint for doing file-backups on Outlook files in Windows:
depending on the user and the usage of the clients PC you might have to create a backup of the outlook files on the client PC because in my experience you cannot copy the outlook.pst if Outlook is open when you try this. ( we used rsync on a win7 machine for this)